# Mapserver wrapping images around international date line

Tags: gis, wms, mapserver

I'm serving GeoTIFF raster images (epsg:4326) via mapserver that wrap across the international date line. Since they span beyond the usual -180 - 180 bounds, I would like the images to be served regardless of which "side" of the coordinate space the query comes from. ie:

```
[...]bbox=150,0,250,90[...]
```

should serve the same image as

```
[...]bbox=-210,0,-110,90[...]
```

is there any way I can communicate to mapserver that it should search current space +/- 360 (and maybe even beyond?) when looking for valid data to fill an image with?